# SettingWithCopyWarning after using copy()

Tags: python, pandas, copy

I have code as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['Alex',10,5,0],['Bob',12,4,1],['Clarke',13,6,0],['brke',15,1,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age','weight','class'],dtype=float) 

df_numeric=df.select_dtypes(include='number')#, exclude=None)[source]
df_non_numeric=df.select_dtypes(exclude='number')

df_non_numeric['class']=df_numeric['class'].copy()
```

it gives me below message

```
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

i want to have `df_non_numeric` independent from `df_numeric`

i used `df_numeric['class'].copy()` based upon suggestions given in other posts.

How could i avoid the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `copy` because [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) is slicing operation, filtering by types of column, check [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/2901002):

```
df_numeric=df.select_dtypes(include='number').copy()
df_non_numeric=df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').copy()
```

If you modify values in `df_non_numeric` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.