# Efficient way to use pandas group by on a million records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which can be generated using the code below

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'subject_ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'colum' : ['L1CreaDate','L1Crea','L2CreaDate','L2Crea','L3CreaDate','L3Crea','L1CreaDate','L1Crea','L2CreaDate','L2Crea'], 
                'dates':['2016-10-30 00:00:00',2.3,'2016-10-30 00:00:00',2.5,np.nan,np.nan,'2016-10-30 00:00:00',12.3,'2016-10-30 00:00:00',12.3]})
```

I am trying to do the below operations on the above dataframe. Though the code works absolutely fine , the issue is when I use the `group by statement`. It's quick in sample dataframe but in real data with over 1 million records, it takes a while and just running for a long time

```
    df2['col2'] = df2['colum'].str.split("Date").str[0]
    df2['col3'] = df2['col2'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['subject_ID','col3'])
    df2['count'] = df2.groupby(['subject_ID','col2'])['dates'].transform(pd.Series.count)
```

I do `groupby` to get the below output `count` column so that I can reject records with count as `0`. There is a logic involved behind dropping NA's. It's not just about dropping all NA's. If you would like to know about that then refer this post [retain few NA's and drop rest of the NA's logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285680/retain-few-nas-and-drop-rest-of-nas-during-stack-operation-in-python)

In real data one person might have more than 10000 rows. So a single dataframe has more than 1 million rows.

Is there any other better and efficient way to do a `groupby` or get the `count` column?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use list comprehension with `split` for improve performance, then not assign output to new column `count` but filtering and last sorting with extracted integers:

```
df2['col2'] = [x.split("Date")[0] for x in df2['colum']]
df2 = df2[df2.groupby(['subject_ID','col2'])['dates'].transform('count').ne(0)].copy()

df2['col3'] = df2['col2'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['subject_ID','col3'])
print (df2)
   subject_ID       colum                dates    col2  col3
0           1  L1CreaDate  2016-10-30 00:00:00  L1Crea     1
1           1      L1Crea                  2.3  L1Crea     1
2           1  L2CreaDate  2016-10-30 00:00:00  L2Crea     2
3           1      L2Crea                  2.5  L2Crea     2
6           2  L1CreaDate  2016-10-30 00:00:00  L1Crea     1
7           2      L1Crea                 12.3  L1Crea     1
8           2  L2CreaDate  2016-10-30 00:00:00  L2Crea     2
9           2      L2Crea                 12.3  L2Crea     2
```

If get error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

it means there are possible missing values, so list comprehension should be changed:

```
df2['col2'] = [x.split("Date")[0] if x == x else np.nan for x in df2['colum']]
```

For check performance:

```
def new(df2):
    df2['col2'] = [x.split("Date")[0] for x in df2['colum']]
    df2 = df2[df2.groupby(['subject_ID','col2'])['dates'].transform('count').ne(0)].copy()
    df2['col3'] = df2['col2'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
    return df2.sort_values(by=['subject_ID','col3'])


def orig(df2):
    df2['col2'] = df2['colum'].str.split("Date").str[0]
    df2['col3'] = df2['col2'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['subject_ID','col3'])
    df2['count'] = df2.groupby(['subject_ID','col2'])['dates'].transform(pd.Series.count)
    return df2[df2['count'].ne(0)]

In [195]: %timeit (orig(df2))
10.8 ms ± 728 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [196]: %timeit (new(df2))
6.11 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Will try now. Thanks for your response

Comment: btw, is it possible to find the execution of time of each cell in jupyter notebook? when I use `%timeit`, it doesn't return anything

Comment: @AVLES - hmmm, try custom function, give me some time for solution.

Comment: Your solution is better than mine in terms of performance, Your knowledge in Python is fantastic and admirable. I have benefited through your answers in forum. Thank you

Comment: just a quick question. Is using `.copy()` function recommended than just assigning to a new dataframe. ex: `df3 = df2.copy()` is recommended/faster than `df3 = df2`

Comment: @AVLES - It depends what need. If need new dataframe with not change original, use copy. if need avoid [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204404/settingwithcopywarning-after-using-copy/55204409#55204409), need copy.

Comment: Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347377/transform-wide-to-long-but-with-repetition-of-a-specific-column